# Warning message: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.1.3

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Estoy intentando creat un marco de datos/ dataframe y continuamente me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.1.3

Después añado el marco de datos y me aparece lo siguiente:

> Universidad < - tibble(personas = c(“Lola”, “Miguel”, “Victoria”),
> Error: unexpected input in "Universidad < - tibble(personas = c(“"
> estudios = c(“Derecho”, “Medicina”, “Psicologia”),
> Error: unexpected input in "estudios = c(“"
> edad = c(18, 22, 35))
> Error: unexpected ')' in "edad = c(18, 22, 35))"

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias!!

Comment: ¡Hola! El mensaje de advertencia y el error que te aparece son asuntos aparte uno del otro; de cualquier manera, para poder darte una mejor respuesta, por favor comparte el código que intentaste ejecutar. En principio, se notan algunos errores de sintaxis, pero no es posible determinarlo sin más información.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

En este código `Universidad < - tibble(personas = c(“Lola”, “Miguel”, “Victoria”)`, el error se debe a que falta un cierre de parentesis al final del código `)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!